# Pandas dataframe multiindex with mixed hierarchy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I don't use pandas that often so I'm not sure if this is possible, or trivial. At least I haven't found anything useful regarding this.

So, I have created somewhat simplified version of my problem. Suppose I have a table of following format. (Note that this is just a hand-drawn generic table from an article, not a representation of a pandas dataframe)

| Name | Orientation | V |  | W |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | **Mean** | **Var** |  |
| a | x | 1 | 6 | +1 |
|  | y |  |  | -1 |
| b | x | 2 | 3 | -2 |
|  | y |  |  | +1 |

OK So this is somewhat messed up, but you see the logic and need behind this kind of structure.

1. Anything under a certain `Name` should point towards to every single data it contains.
2. `Orientation` here is not a measurement; it is a sub-property each `Name` has, and `W` is determined by that `Orientation` as well. On the other hand, `V` is a feature characteristic to `Name`, and thus does not depend on `Orientation`.
3. Some columns have multiple values; here `V` is such variable, it consists of `Mean` and `Var`. On the other hand, `W` does not.

So my question is how to construct this into a `DataFrame`. My best effort so far is

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1, 6,], ['b', 2, 3,]], columns=['Name', 'Mean', 'Var']).set_index('Name')
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'x', +1,], ['a', 'y', -1,], ['b', 'x', -2,], ['b', 'y', 1,]], 
                   columns=['Name', 'Orientation', 'W']).set_index(['Name', 'Orientation'])
```

I am not even sure how I could make `V` column into multiple ones, and all I have is just make columns without any hierarchy. Also I haven't managed to merge these two dataframes without repeating V values for each orientation;

```
df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True,)
```

would yield

| Name | Orientation | Mean | Var | W |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | x | 1 | 6 | +1 |
|  | y | 1 | 6 | -1 |
| b | x | 2 | 3 | -2 |
|  | y | 2 | 3 | +1 |

which is far from what I want.

Ideally, what I want is,

1. `df.loc['a']['V','Mean']` yields 1
2. `df.loc['a','y']['W']` yields -1

So, is there any way to fit this table of mixed hierarchy into pandas dataframe structure?

Comment: Will you please add code to create the original dataframe?

Comment: @user17242583 I don't think that's necessary. This is perfectly equivalent working example.

Comment: @user17242583 or, if you're asking the first table at the top of the question; that is not a dataframe, that is a table I want to hammer into the dataframe structure.

Comment: Then will you please send the code so that I get my hands on that table?

Comment: @user17242583 Isn't that what I posted already in the question? I am not sure what you're asking about.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. :) You say "table", but what exactly do you mean? You used markdown table syntax to display the table in the question, but how does your code know what the table is, you know?

Comment: @user17242583 That is exactly what my question is about. The markdown table in the top of the question is a simplified version of what I have to deal with that I found on an academic paper. I want that table to fit into a dataframe structure so that I could manipulate with, but I cannot make things behave in the ways I expect it to behave. The best effort to make that happen is the code I posted in the middle of the question.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhh, I see. So the first table is what you _want_, and the second table is what you've been able to achieve so far?

Comment: @user17242583 Exactly. English is not my first language and I'm not even a python developer and I don't even use pandas extensively, so I'm sorry for the confusion. :)

Comment: No no, it's really not your fault at all. I read many, many questions a day, almost all of them have their expected output at the end, and so I just expected that from habit. It's not you :)